# Fetch JSONObject value from a JSON data object

Tags: java, json

I have following json data

```
{
    "TestMetrics": {
        "ProcessPID": "7887",
        "MemSwapped": "0",      
        "Uptime": "407",
        "webTiming": "{\"domainLookupStart\":3,\"domainLookupEnd\":67}"}
}
```

From this i need to fetch the webTiming json object.
For that i used following code

```
 JSONObject launchMetricsObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);


        try {
        JSONObject objc = launchMetricsObj.getJSONObject("TestMetrics");

        JSONObject webtimingObj = objc.getJSONObject("webTiming");
        System.out.println(webtimingObj:::::: " +webtimingObj);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
        }
```

As the "webTiming" value is  a `JSONObject` i tried to get it as

```
JSONObject webtimingObj = objc.getJSONObject("webTiming");
```

But I observed following Exception:

```
JSON Objectorg.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["webTiming"] is not a JSONObject.
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because `webTiming` is defined as a string, not `JSONObject`.

In order to convert it, you need to do:

```
JSONObject webtimingObj = new JSONObject(objc.getString("webTiming"));
```